# multiple find and update mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have an app with rest api in node js and mongodb as database. A user can login from multiple devices and i need to sync users all devices contacts in db more than 5000 contacts in each device.

Example:
User A register from Device D1 and i save user contacts in mongo db. if same user login from another device D2 then i need to sync Device 1 and device 2 contacts in mongo db  but contacts will be unique. if User A have number in D1 +xxx-xxx-xxx and same number without country code xx-xxx--xxx then previous number will be overwritten by new number.

At the same time i need to send the all existing contacts to app users.

my code is working fine at logical level but it takes approx 60 to 90 seconds. what should i do to increase the performance so that the sync is done quickly?

Comment: Please mention the queries that you are using.

Comment: here is my query which run in loop more then 4000

db.collection('contacts').update(
 {user_id:ObjectId("571dd1de716221be3dfd93c5"),formatted_phone_number:formatted_phone},
 {$set:{user_id:ObjectId("571dd1de716221be3dfd93c5"),formatted_phone_number:formatted_phone,phone_number:phone, name:username}},
 { upsert: true },
 function(err, result){
 }
)

Comment: Does the collection has any indexes?

Comment: yes user_id and formatted_phone_number with indexes